# How to automatically start deployed war in Jboss?

Tags: deployment, jboss, wildfly, auto

I am using eclipse and i have made a maven jersey project that run on the JBoss 
 server when i press right click on the project and then run on server.
Is there a way to make the project run automatically when the JBoss start?
I mean without doing the run on server thing?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the servers tab -> right click on Jboss server -> Add and Remove and add your desired project. This will deploy the selected project on Jboss deployments folder.

[image]

After that you only have to make sure the server is Synchronized and start Jboss. Your project will deploy automatically.